# Windows 8 - Fancy Progress Bars API?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, windows-8

Does anyone know if the new 'fancy' file transfer progress bar that Windows 8 uses for its file transfer progress is available via some API (preferably C#)? I could think of some useful places for it in our application but can't seem to find out if it's consumable or internally available only to Windows.

**EDIT**

My answer below now includes a WPF implementation that I wrote that you may use in your own projects :)

[image: Screenshot of a Windows 8 file operation dialog with the fancy progress bars]

Comment: it probably will be eventually, around the release of windows 8

Comment: @Ryathal: Was hoping for more of a concrete answer - we already have a lot of development resources for Metro style apps on Windows 8, I'm assuming there's some information about stuff like this too somewhere.

Comment: I've emailed someone on the Microsoft team - author of the following blog to see if I can find out more http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2011/08/23/improving-our-file-management-basics-copy-move-rename-and-delete.aspx

Comment: Seeing as its a desktop feature; it probably won't be available to outside developers. Microsoft seems to have only improved the developer interface for Metro; which is sad, because I can't see why people would want to use Metro as end-users.

Comment: For anyone who's interested I've started trying to create my own in WPF. Once it's completed I'll post up a link to the source or a DLL.

Comment: See my answer for a WPF version of this control

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For all those interested, I have implemented a WPF version of this progress bar avaliable from my blog [here](http://wrightdev.wordpress.com/2012/06/05/wpf-ratebar/) (linking so I've only 1 place to keep a valid active link). I decided it was better than waiting for something available only on Windows 8 or not available at all. I hope you find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatley I wouldn't expect any Windows 8 related API support until the release or a few weeks before Windows 8 is rolled out. It might even be included within a new Visual Studio service pack some time in the near future.