# WPF Binding and historical values

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I'm currently writing a WPF progress bar that includes a rate (see [Windows 8 - Fancy Progress Bars API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9978078/windows-8-fancy-progress-bars-via-c)).

The screenshot below shows what I've got so far (left) and a badly done all in code as part of my learning exercise (right). I'm now trying to convert the code version to use as much XAML as possible.

[image]

I've got most of the way there by creating a new class called [RateBase](http://pastebin.com/FCb5m8ex) and implementing it in a similar way to RangeBase. I've then added a new instance and provided a template file [RangeGraph](http://pastebin.com/r6sxNj0K). I'm attempting to do this as by the book as possible, but I'm not sure how to tackle the final stage.

I now wish to add a graph, this graph is to display the rate as it has changed historically as the progress has progressed. I have 'Rate' as a value I can bind to, but I believe somwhere I need a Double[] containing my historical rate values. My question is where should this be placed (I don't really want to pollute RateBase) and how do I bind to it from my template (I don't believe I can bind to RangeGraph.cs if I add properties on there or am I wrong?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, you will need historical Data. In my opinion, whenever the bound Dependency Property `Rate` changes, you should move the old value into an IEnumerable that's defined on the graph control itself (The same place that has the DP) and use that to draw the lines. I personally would create a class named MyControlData and add an instance of that to the control.

You might also want to add a `Timer` and move the current Rate to the IEnumerable when it Elapses, so longer streaks of the same rate will appear as multiple bars. Depends on how you actually determine progress. You might get into the following dilemma here : The `Rate` changes at a different interval than the `Percentage` in most cases - what floats your boat?

Keeping the history in your control's scope leaves your application agnostic to the history of your Rate, but lets your control display it as required.

To use DataBinding in a UserControl, edit the `<UserControl x:Name="myControl">` node in Control.xaml and add a name like shown here. Wherever you want to bind, refer to `ElementName=myControl`. Please note that you will have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged on the Control (or on MyControlData) if you want to achieve this - or, and that would be advisable, directly implement it as a dependency property.

And BTW, if you have no idea how to achieve what you intend to have a look into `ItemsControl`. I think what you want to do can easily be achieved by means as simple as using `ItemsControl` and `ItemsTemplate`, where the ItemsSource is your historical data and the ItemTemplate depicts your current rate in comparison to your MaxRate. MaxRate is another property you can set from the DependencyProperty `Rate`'s changed handler.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I didn't intend to place the historical values on the 'RateBase' but I may change my mind as per your suggestion. You pointed out a very valid point regarding the update or progress & rate possibly being independent which I need to consider, however the X value of the bound points relates to the progress when the rate changed, so it may not be an issue. I'll take a look at the ItemsControl stuff. I've managed to get an implementation working with an ObservableCollection on the RateGraph.cs (code behind for template) but not sure it's the best approach.