# Is there an API for the Windows 8 progress dialog API?

Tags: windows-8, progress

Is there an API for the new Windows 8 progress dialog?

Here we see a Windows 8 progress dialog in its natural habitat; extracting a `.zip` file:

[image]

**Note**: i use the term *"progress dialog"* to refer to a *dialog* that indicates *progress*. Not to be confused with the Windows Shell *"Progress Dialog"*, which has a supported [`IProgressDialog` api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775248(v=vs.85).aspx).

My quick perusal of the [**MSDN Windows 8 Technologies**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh920512.aspx) list showed nothing that looked similar to something that might be related to an area of interest that i'm looking into. (i.e. just because i said it, doesn't make it true. [No reason to close the question](https://superuser.com/questions/524439/how-safe-is-my-windows-8-microsoft-account))

Comment: It's not made available (yet) to us lowly app developers.  See the forum thread [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9978078/windows-8-fancy-progress-bars-via-c) - one fine gent has [rolled his own](http://wrightdev.wordpress.com/2012/06/05/wpf-ratebar/).

Comment: @SandraWalters: Nice to be referred to as a fine gent :) Shame I never had the opportunity to use my creation in a project though :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9978078/windows-8-fancy-progress-bars-via-c), there is no official one available out there yet.
However, you may find some custom developed ones on the Internet.