# hiding progress window during file transfer

Tags: vb6

I have some older visual basic programs I wrote that run every hour to transfer files between folders.

The VB programs work fine (compiled into EXE) on my new laptop with Windows 8. But occasionally when the copy operation of a file is delayed or lags in Windows, the mini progress window appears in the foreground (preparing to copy, x% complete).

This is annoying while I'm trying to work on my laptop.

On this thread, you can see a screenshot of what this progress windows looks like (similar not exact) 
  [Is there an API for the Windows 8 progress dialog API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14064017/is-there-an-api-for-the-windows-8-progress-dialog-api)

To copy files, I'm using

```
FileCopy oldfile, newfile
```

I also can use

```
bSuccess = ShellFileCopy(oldfile, newfile)
```

Is there any attribute I can set with either of these commands, to disable or minimize the  progress mini window during file transfers?

Alternately, is there another command or shell extension I can try, that does allow me to disable or minimize the  progress mini window during file transfers?

Answer (score 0):

Here are two additional ways you can try:

```
With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    .CopyFile oldFile, newFile, True    ' (True overwrites, if it exists)
End With
```

Or (use the command-line `copy`):

```
With CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    .Run "%comspec% /c copy """ & oldFile & """ """ & newFile & """", 0, True
End With
```

Comment: Thanks, does either of these ways disable the progress windows?

Comment: Give them a try. I would be surprised if the second one displays a progress window.